# reportlab prints unicode char instead of bullet

Tags: python, python-2.7, reportlab

On testing the example mentioned in this [How can I make the bullet appear directly next to the text of an indented list in the reportlab package for python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996458/how-can-i-make-the-bullet-appear-directly-next-to-the-text-of-an-indented-list-i) question, unicode chars are printed instead of bullets.

Here is my code..

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, ListFlowable, ListItem, SimpleDocTemplate, Frame
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.colors import CMYKColor

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("SOtest.pdf")
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
Story = []
Story.append(Paragraph("Header Text, I dont want the bullets directly below the H"
                       ,styles['Normal']))
style = styles['Normal']
t = ListFlowable(
        [
        # Paragraph("Item no.1", style),
        ListItem(Paragraph("Item no. 2", style),bulletColor="green",value='circle'),
        ListItem(Paragraph('sublist item 2', style),bulletColor='red',value='circle'),
        ],
        bulletType="bullet",
        start='circle',
        leftIndent=50,
)

Story.append(t)
doc.build(Story)
```

On the resultant pdf, I got

```
Header Text, I dont want the bullets directly below the H
\u25cf Item no. 2
\u25cf sublist item 2
```

Comment: Have you tried using `unicode` strings for the literal items?

Comment: I tried adding `\u018e` char inside the paragraph text. But it still prints the same `\u018e` char in output.. Seems like no parsing happens.

Comment: But did you try using `unicode` strings, e.g. `u"Item no. 2"`?

Comment: Your title is [confusing me](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2022/index.htm).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it prints `Item no. 2`